# Python use %s in dict to call value

Tags: python, dictionary

How can we use dict similar to the following?

```
dict[%s] % variable
```

For those who are interested in what I am trying to do exactly, I have three dicts:

```
    dict_1 = {'a':'123', 'b':'234', 'c':'345'}
    dict_2 = {'d':'456', 'e':'567', 'f':'678'}
    dict_3 = {'a':'e', 'b':'d', 'c':'f'}
```

And I have a function where I need to input something like:

```
    function(dict_1['a'], dict_2['e']) #according to dict_3 that 'a' is paired with 'e'.
```

Edited:

I was trying to write a for loop to loop over all the dicts and have them pair dict_1 and dict_2 pairs into the function according to dict_3. I actually don't need the %s thing after looking at you guys answer. That's what happens what you try to code without coffee in the morning lol.

And in the end, this following did what I wanted, thanks all!:

```
    for i in dict_1:
         results = function(dict_1[i],dict_2[dict_3[i]]
```

Comment: None of that example code shows what you want to use `%` for (or why).  Can you not just do `my_dict[variable]` directly?

Comment: Are you just looking for `dict_2[dict_3['a']]`?

Comment: You should use the variable directly instead of d["%s" % var], like so d[var] , if var is not a string then d[str(var)]. This is less confusing and better syntax i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what I gather is correct, you were almost already on the money. You can just write it like this:

```
dict["%s" % variable]
```

One issue with this, however, is that if you had something like:

```
   d = {3 : 'hello'}
   my_key = 3
   d['%s' % my_key]
```

That would fail with a `KeyError`

Regardless though, it is kind of a roundabout way to use it. You can just write:

```
dict[otherdict['a']]
```

Comment: Your first one is no different than `dict[variable]` (assuming `variable` is already a string like in the question)

Comment: I know. But his question was how to write it that way. So I showed him.

Comment: To fully understand the `%` operator's positioning: It is just the actual modulo operation overloaded for strings. The left operand must be a string and the right a single value of any kind or a collection

Answer (score 3):

```
function(dict_1['a'], dict_2[dict_3['a']])
```

should work.

So i'd do something like

```
k = 'a'
function(dict_1[k],dict_2[dict_3[k]])
```

Using the % operator here doesn't make much sense to me because you're not trying to produce a string with some static data and a variably inserted value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `%` operator is evaluated before than `[]` operator. You should do `dict["%s" % variable]` or more easier `dict[variable]` if `variable` is already a string.

Answer (score 2):

If your variables are strings, you then use them as keys directly

```
dict[variable]
```

For the function you want to do, you can call

```
function(dict1[variable], dict2[dict3[variable]])
```

If you are trying to call this function for every key and value in dict3, you may want to just iterate over dict3.

```
for key, val in dict3.items():
  function(dict1[key], dict2[values])
```

For a more pythonic way of collecting these results into a list

```
func_results = [function(dict1[key], dict2[val]) for key, val in dict3.items()]
```

One final thing. If you just have dict3 there for the purpose of this function call, a list of tuples is all you need:

```
arg_list = [('a', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'f')]
func_results = [function(dict1[arg1], dict2[arg2]) for arg1, arg2 in arg_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the keys were integers instead of strings, you will have to do:

`dict[int("%d" % some_integer)]`